# disconnect a client from server TCP

Tags: c

I write a server/client  TCP application in C .Many clients can be connected to the server at the same time. How can a client be disconnected after 10 seconds he called close()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) and [close](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) on the accepted socket file descriptor, providing you're talking about vanilla Berkely sockets in a UNIX of some kind.

You'll have to manage the time out in whatever way is appropriate to the architecture of your application. You'll have to run a timer *somewhere*, there is no way to automatically get the O/S to time out an active connection.

Comment: shutdown() worked but what about the time of 10 seconds ? The client should be disconnected from the server after this time.

Comment: I've clarified my answer to address that a little. How are you multiplexing your socket? Threads? Select/Poll? Async signals?

Comment: You could set a timeout on select then.

Comment: I think the timeout parameter of the select() call is for waiting a socket to be connected in that specified time. I think the time of 10 seconds after the socket should be closed need to be set with an option of the socket like SO_LINGER , but it doesn't work.

Comment: The timeout on select will be for *everything* you have in the set to select on. You'll have to decide from selects return call *why* it dropped through. I really wouldn't mess with SO_LINGER, it's there for a reason! If you're doing anything with sockets in UNIX you must have this book - http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html

Answer (score 3):

Call `close` on the socket 10 seconds after you `accept` it.