# Tcp Client/Server - Client messages issue

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have client and server application.

I have the client disconnect from the server with client.close via a disconnect button.

I send a message, shows on server. ok works great.

I disconnect and then reconnect. I send a message. It shows the message two times.

I disconnect another time then reconnect. I send a message. It then shows the message three times.

It is incrementing the message and sending it multiple times after the disconnect and then reconnect.

Help? Been trying to figure this out for a while

[SERVER]

```
Public Class Server
Dim Listener As TcpListener
Dim Client As TcpClient
Dim ListenerThread As System.Threading.Thread
Dim ClientID As String
Dim ClientIP As String
Dim ClientIPandID As String
Dim ClientIPandPort As String
Dim TotalItemCount As String
Dim clientcount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Server_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
    If TextBoxPort.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Port To Run On.")
    Else

        ListenerThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Listening)
        ListenerThread.IsBackground = True
        ListenerThread.Start(TextBoxPort.Text)
        ButtonStart.Enabled = False
        ButtonStop.Enabled = True
        ListBox1.Items.Add("[SERVER] Running on Port " + TextBoxPort.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("[SERVER] Waiting For A Connection...")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Listening(ByVal Port As Integer)

    Try
        Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port)
        Listener.Start()
        Do
            Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient 'Accepts Client Trying To Connect
            If Client.Connected Then
                MsgBox("Client Connected")
            End If
            clientcount += 1
            GetClientInfo() 'Retrieves The Clients Info
            AddHandler ReceivedMessage, AddressOf ReceivedMessage1
        Loop Until False
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
'Events
Public Event ReceivedMessage(ByVal Command As String)

Private Sub GenerateClientSessionNumber()
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim x As String = String.Empty
    For i = 0 To 7
        x &= Chr(r.Next(65, 89))
    Next
    ClientID = x
End Sub

Private Sub GetClientInfo()
    GenerateClientSessionNumber()
    ClientIPandID = Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Remove(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().LastIndexOf(":")) & " - " & ClientID
    ClientIP = Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Remove(Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().LastIndexOf(":"))
    ClientIPandPort = Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()
    MsgBox(ClientIPandPort)
    ListBox2.Items.Add(ClientIPandID)
    Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonStop.Click
    Listener.Stop()
    Client.Close()
    ButtonStop.Enabled = False
    ButtonStart.Enabled = True
    ListBox1.Items.Add("[SERVER] Server Stopped")
End Sub


Private Sub Reading()
    Try
        Dim Reader As New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)

        Dim Command As String = Reader.ReadLine

        Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
            RaiseEvent ReceivedMessage(command)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub ReceivedMessage1(ByVal Command As String)
    Dim Message() As String = Command.Split("|")
    If Message(0) = "MESSAGE" Then
        MsgBox("Message Received From Client " + ">" + Message(1))
    End If
end sub
```

[CLIENT]

```
Public Class Client
Dim Client As New TcpClient
Sub Connect(ByVal ServerIP As String, ByVal Port As Integer)
    'Try To Make Connection With Server
    If Client.Connected = True Then
        MsgBox("Already Connected")
        MsgBox("Connected To " + Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString)
    Else
        MsgBox("Currently Not Connected. Trying To Connect...")
        Try
            Client.Connect(ServerIP, Port)
            MsgBox("Connected")
            Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Reading, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Could Not Connect To Server. Check Server." + ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub SendData(ByVal Message As String) 'Sends Data to Server
    TextBox1.Text = Message
    Try
        If Client.Connected = True Then
            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream)
            Writer.WriteLine(Message)
            Writer.Flush()
        Else
            MsgBox("Cannot Send Message. Connection To Server Is Not Active.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You Are Not Connected To The Server." + vbCrLf + ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonConnect.Click
    Connect(TextBoxIPAddress.Text, TextBoxPort.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSendMessage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSendMessage.Click
    SendData("MESSAGE|" & TextBoxMessage.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Client_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub    


Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    SendData("DISCONNECT|")
    Client.Close()
    Client = New TcpClient
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure about the problem but i can give you some hypothesizes, firstly you add handler on every **client** you connect on **server** side and that means multiple pointer to the same place, secondly when you connect to server and **reconnect** you actually don't tell the **server** that the two clients are the same so he make two **channels** between the client and the server, the first is the **old** one that **didn't close** and he still have handler on it, the server don't recognize that the first is **disconnected** because he is connected! even if its another object at client. so when client **disconnects** , **disconnect** him from **server** too, or at **every loop** test if clients are connected before accepting do this test .

Comment: how do I do that. I have tried using methods for disconnecting client.client

Comment: @CharlesJohnson i think you should call Close
see this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159150/disconnect-a-client-from-server-tcp

Answer (score -1):

Since I have a class Called "ConnectedClient". I was able to make a call to that specific client or all clients and Close/Destroy the connection.